# Where is news app in iOS 9 beta?

Tags: ios

I'm a developer and was able to download the new iOS beta yesterday. However, the new News app was missing. Does it not go public for a while?

Answer (score 1):

Apple news will be available in a few number of countries (not specified in the keynote).

The [foot note on iOS 9 on Apple website](https://www.apple.com/ios/ios9-preview/) does not have any clues on availability on every announced app. Just say the following:

> Features are subject to change. Some features may not be available in
>   all regions or all languages.

Comment: I'm in the U.S.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Go to Settings > General > Language and Region, select USA. Restart your device...

If your location is already United states, change to anything else, and then repeat the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

My experience is that news is a bit cranky. You should be able to tell if it's hidden in a folder by searching in spotlight and looking to the right of the name.

Worst case, erase all content and settings on the device and see if it shows up. If not you may have to restore the device and not restore your backup to see news in action.